# rampart security with eclipse and axis 2

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis, rampart

SO i've created my first web service using axis 2 and eclipse following this tutorial

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html

Now i want to add a security to this web service so i downloaded rampart. But I haven't found tutorial for how to use rampart with eclipse and where exactly to put this .mar files and .jar files

If you have some good beginning tutorial or link or similar problem which you resolved  I will appreciate any help;

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good tutorial for doing just that on Eclipse. Page 19 goes through the configuration details and steps to secure your Web Service using WS Security. There you will also find details on securing via SSL.

http://jkrzemie.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/ws.pdf